# Check if thread is EDT is necessary?

Tags: java, swing, events, event-dispatch-thread

I have an UI implemented with Swing. One component does some work that may take some time, so I use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. However, I was reading some old code and found this in an `ActionListener`:

```
if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             // code X
         }
    });
} else {
   // code X
}
```

I thought that it made sense since it separates `code X` from the EDT. However, I found it error-prone since I have used it a couple of times and both times I forgot the `else` part.

The question is: is the `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` checking necessary? Or could I <strike>assume that I am not in the EDT and</strike> always use `invokeLater`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you simply **always** use `invokeLater()`? It works on the EDT as well and if your code can handle "code x" running "later", then it can also handle that if it's running in the EDT. (By the way, you could simply extract that into a `invokeNowOrLater()` method where you pass in a `Runnable`).

Comment: That's exactly my question... I'll edit it so it's a bit more clear

Comment: I see. I was just confused by the "should I assume that I am not in the EDT", because that's not a pre-requisite to calling `invokeLater()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Invoking later is fine even if you are on the EDT, however it certainly changes the timing of events, so you have to be sure that you were not dependent on the sequence of the code here when you were on the EDT. That being said, a simple way to avoid forgetting the else is to wrap the call in a utility method:

```
public static void invokeInDispatchThreadIfNeeded(Runnable runnable) {
    if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
        runnable.run();
    } else {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

That way you never forget the `else`.

Also, in general in your idom repeating `code x` is a very bad idea, as you may find later that you have to fix or improve that code and you will only do it in one place, leaving a bug in the other.

Comment: I agree... it's not DRY at all to do that.

Comment: Wait a tick... shouldn't it be `if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread())` ?

Comment: @YuppieNetworking, if you are on the EDT, then you can call the Runnable.run() method directly. If you are not, then you need to call invokelater.

Answer (score 2):

I *believe* for your particular use case, checking `isEventDispatchThread()` is unnecessary. Directly calling `invokeLater()` will not create a new thread, so this occurs no performance penalty.

Comment: Thank you. In which case it is necessary?

Comment: @YuppieNetworking: well, one case where it may be necessary is when you do **not** want to run something on the EDT (like a very lenghty computation)

Answer (score 0):

The code really ought to know if it is on the EDT or not (if that is relevant). So `java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread` should be left to assertions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "The code" ? The code the user writes/is responsible for or the implementation of `invokeLater`? I guess the latter one? Thanks.

Comment: @ceran The former. The latter is an implementation of a public API so cannot tell which thread it is called on.

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you have on your code a thread(A)launch by the EDT, and in that thread(A) you have another thread(B) which have to modify your GUI, in that case you have to use invokeLater on thread(B). However, if the modification of your GUI is doing by first thread(A) it's not necessary to use invokeLater.